# Rails 3 routes and modules

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a AR model inside a module

```
class Long::Module::Path::Model < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and want to use following routes (without the module names, because it's easier to write and remember)

```
resources :models
```

buts Rails 3 always wants to use a URL like

```
long_module_path_model_url
```

Is there are way to change this behavior?

Hope anyone out there can help me?

Mario

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little curious why you're referencing a model when talking about routing which only handles the controller level; but this article should be helpful: [R3 Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

"If you want to route /photos (without the prefix /admin) to Admin::PostsController, you could use:

```
scope :module => "admin" do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

"

If you'd like the named paths to change, you can use :as, as specified here: [R3 Prefixing the Named Routes Helpers](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers)

So I'm guessing something along the lines of

**1:**

```
scope :module => 'long/module/path' do
   resources :model, :as => :model
end
```

**or 2:**

```
scope :module => 'long' do
  scope :module => 'module' do 
   scope :module => 'path' do
    resources :model, :as => :model
   end end end
```

Is what you're looking for.

Comment: Nope, you didn't understand me ;) I want to access my models with model_path(@model), and not with long_module_path_model(@model). Seems not to be working.

Comment: Perhaps the revised version above is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :your_looooooong_model_name, :as => :short
```

Would give you shorts_url, etc.

Comment: Nope, sorry didn't worked for me... Got lots of routing errors now.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but the others misunderstood your question and didn't solve your problem.

You need to override the model_name method as below:

```
class Long::Module::Path::Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(Long::Module::Path::Model, nil, "YourNewModelName")
  end
end
```

Credit goes to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843193/rails-namescoped-model-object-without-module-prefix-route-path#comment15752141_11843937).