# Using rails3 namespace question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes, reference

I am a new guy, a java programmer.

Using namespace encountered difficulties in rails3.

```
rails g scaffold ns::e1 name:string  
rails g model ns::e2 name:string e1:references  
rake db:migrate
```

edit app/models/ns/e1.rb

```
class Ns::E1 < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :e2s  
end
```

edit app/views/ns/e1s/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>  
<p>  
  <b>Name:</b>  
  <%=@ns_e1.name%>  
</p>  
<%= form_for([@ns_e1, @ns_e1.e2s.build]) do |f| %>  
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.label :name %>  
    <br/>  
    <%= f.text_field :name %>  
  </div>  
  <div class="actions">  
    <%= f.submit %>  
  </div>  
<% end %>  
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ns_e1_path(@ns_e1)%>|  
<%= link_to 'Back', ns_e1s_path %>
```

Error is **undefined method `ns_e1_ns_e2s_path'**

How to configure routes.rb ? Thanks

Thanks ream88, I found a solution.

Edit the routes.rb.

```
namespace :ns do
  resources :e1s do
    resources :e2s, :as => :ns_e2s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've  used named-spaced models since I started with Rails back in 2007, and unfortunately Rails isn't very good at handling name-spaces. Its very better now with Rails 3, but you still have to write more code than usual. [And I'm always ending up, writing my own routes **without** namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062704/rails-3-routes-and-modules). For example:

I have following two models:

```
class MyAwesomeBlog::User < AR::Base
end

class MyAwesomeBlog::Post < AR::Base
end

# routes.rb
resources :users
resources :posts
```

Is this an option for you?

Comment: Thanks, According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062704/rails-3-routes-and-modules  I found a solution.