# Rails namescoped model object without module prefix route path 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes, nested-routes

i have problem little bit with Rails router and form generator.
My application have namespaced modules for models and controllers. Module is used to easier abstraction to another projects.

I using in `routes.rb` scope method instead namespace, because i wan't have "ugly" path helpers.

It looks like:

```
scope module: :taxonomy do
  resources :taxonomies do
    resources :terms
  end
end
```

Problem is that when i want to edit taxonomy (url: `taxonomies/1/edit`) i get an error:

```
undefined method `taxonomy_taxonomy_path'
```

cause my route is instead only `taxonomy_path`

is there any way how reach `form_for @taxonomy` to recognize that route is scoped? without used `form_for @taxonomy, url: taxonomy_path(@taxonomy)` which is not cure. Because @taxonomy object in controller methods within `respond_with @taxonomy` always refereces to `taxonomy_taxonomy_url`

my models:

```
module Taxonomy
  class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taxonomy_terms, inverse_of: :taxonomy
    has_many :terms, through: :taxonomy_terms
  class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :taxonomy_term, inverse_of: :term
    has_one :taxonomy, through: :taxonomy_term
```

and controllers:

```
module Taxonomy
  class TaxonomiesController < ApplicationController
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override ActiveRecord's model naming by:

```
module Taxonomy
  class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.model_name
      ActiveModel::Name.new("Taxonomy")
    end
  end
end
```

This overrides ActiveRecord default naming generation which generates taxonomy_taxonomy name for the Taxonomy class since it is under Taxonomy module.
It should solve your routing name problem and generate a proper route name as you wish.

Comment: I have one question about this. Solution with change model name out of namespace is perfect when i wan't to access models without namespace prefix "Taxonomy::". But is there any issues when it should be critical, like poor isolation of module models, non-standard Rails behaviour or something?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question - you mean that you now access the class Taxonomy by `Taxonomy` instead of `Taxonomy::Taxonomy` in your code?

Comment: My bad, of course not, it calls Module, not Model. My question is that change model name isn't contra productive when i want only route paths/urls to be without prefix. Like future problems with upgrade Rails etc...

Comment: Fixed first comment. Must be defined as `ActiveModel::Name.new("Taxonomy::Taxonomy", nil, "Taxonomy")`

Comment: What version of rails are you on?

Comment: 3.2.7 and when is my project still in development i update to the newest.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in routes.rb:

```
namespace :taxonomy do
  resources :taxonomies do
    resources :terms
  end
end
```

This will probably require you to store your controllers in a subdirectory named `taxonomy` as well.

Comment: This works, but path is with taxonomy_ prefix. I used "scope module" to have prettier paths.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you need to add a Module to your Class because of your folder structure.

```
  app/models
  ├── ...
  ├── taxonomy
  │   ├── taxonomy.rb
  │   └── ...
  └── ...
```

---

You can config rails to load your **models** located in subfolders recursively:

*Config your `config/application.rb`:*

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'models', "taxonomy", '**/') ]
```

*You can set this config for any folder and subfolder in your rails app.*

---

If you do that you will not have to override an ActiveRecord's model, which is not always the best idea.

```
class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```