# Namespaces route and model path rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, routes, namespaces

I'm just started with rails and until now I was very happy with it, but there is one thing I can't figure out.

I have some ActiveRecords models in a namespace "Monitor", and I have some controllers in a Namespace "Settings". What I want to accomplish is that I can use the namespaced models in my settings controllers/forms.

I've got this:

**/config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :settings do
  resources :queues, :channels
end
```

**/app/controllers/settings/queus_controller.rb**

```
class Settings::QueuesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @queue = Monitor::Queue.new()
    render 'form', :layout => false
  end

  def create
    @queue = Monitor::Queue.new(post_params)

    if (@queue.save)
      @status = 'added'
      render 'success'
    else
      render 'form', :layout => false
    end
  end

  def edit
    @queue = Monitor::Queue.find(params[:id])
    render 'form', :layout => false
  end

  ...
end
```

**/app/models/monitor/queue.rb**

```
module Monitor
  class Queue < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

**/app/views/settings/form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @queue do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Now Rails is complaining about a missing method : `monitor_queues_path` or Rails generates a path like `/monitor/queues` instead of `/settings/queues(:new/edit)`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

Aah I found it!

This post gave me the proper solution:
[Rails namescoped model object without module prefix route path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843193/rails-namescoped-model-object-without-module-prefix-route-path?rq=1)

The problem came from the prefix from the ActiveRecord class:

```
module Monitor
  class Queue < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

This should be

```
module Monitor
  class Queue < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.model_name
      ActiveModel::Name.new("Monitor::Queue", nil, "Queue")
    end
  end
end
```

After changing this I only needed to change the form_for in the correct way:

```
<%= form_for [:settings, @queue] do |f| %>
```

And that fixes it :D

Comment: this is just awesome

Answer (score 1):

You are using nesting for your `Queue` models. Therefore your `form_for` call needs to know about the parent model too.  So in your case you nested `Queue` under `Setting` so you will need to provide a `setting` object as well.  I'm guessing in your controller you made a `@setting` variable.  If this is the case then the following code will work for you.

```
<%= form_for [@setting, @queue] do |f| %>
    <%# Your form code here -%>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: No I'm just using the namespace to provide the correct paths. @settings is not a object or what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from my friend @mkhairi he said to use this on the parent model :

```
class YourParentModel < ApplicationRecord
      def self.use_relative_model_naming?
        true
      end
end
```

then you can use back ur lovely short path.

Source :
https://coderwall.com/p/heed_q/rails-routing-and-namespaced-models